# Jython sending array of java File objects to java class from python

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm having what I believe is a python string issue. The goal is to send a java class an array of File objects from python/Jython. I'm getting a error related to the string path sent to the File constructor. I believe it is because i can't seem to get rid of the double slash. python code below:

```
from java.io import File
from jarray import array

myPath ='C:\\something\\somethingElse'
onlyfiles = [ abspath(join(myPath,f)) for f in listdir(myPath) if isfile(join(myPath,f))]

jythonArray = array(onlyfiles, String)
temp=array(onlyfiles,File)
```

I get the error "TypeError: can't convert 'C:\..." to Java.io.File
I have also tried .replace('\\','\') in the comprehension to no avail. It works when i just type out the full path in a string and send it to a java.File object. The issue seems to be I can't get rid of the \'s in the path using the comprehension. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `onlyfiles` is a list of strings (`<type 'str'>`), not a list of files. Recall that normally in Python file paths are handled simply as strings and that the `os.path.*` methods take a string and return a string.

Therefore you need to make Java `File`s out of the strings. One way is like this:

```
onlyjavafiles = [File(f) for f in onlyfiles]
```

A full example therefore looks like this (Note I added the missing imports):

```
from java.io import File
from java.lang import String
from jarray import array, zeros
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, abspath

myPath = '/tmp'
onlyfiles = [abspath(join(myPath, f)) for f in listdir(myPath) if isfile(join(myPath, f))]
onlyjavafiles = [File(f) for f in onlyfiles]

jythonArray = array(onlyfiles, String)
temp = array(onlyjavafiles, File)
```

Comment: It worked great thank you! i had misunderstood the docs. array() doesn't make a list of Files by running your list of strings through a File constructor. It just defines the type of the array. got it!